# Connecting to MySQL server with Unity3d?

Tags: c#, android, mysql, unity-game-engine, odbc

I am trying to create an Android game that needs to send information to be stored in a remote database. The MySQL database is stored on my university's server, which I usually access through SSH. What I'm trying to do right now is to use ODBC to connect to the database, but I am having trouble getting it to interact with Unity3d (C#). If anybody has experience with this, I would appreciate any help or direction to get my past this hurdle!

Comment: There are two issues with this question, MySQL clients on Mono, especially on the .Net 3.5 Unity subset are notorious for it's poor support for it's MySQL and Data libraries. The second idsue is, why would you want to connect directly to a database? This is a huge security risk, which can be solved by an API, written in a language of choice(PHP, uby, Python, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Unity Wiki have defined a complete procedure ([Server side high score](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores)) with PHP, MySql and C#/JavaScript. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: The example on you rlink uses secret keys on both server and the client, this is a security issue since de-compiling the client app is easy. If security is important - don't implement this!

Comment: so what and how you gonna implement it?

Comment: Without *hard coded key*. The user submit username and password, and get a token/key/sessionID back from the server - this key is unique for the user and can not be obtained from the code. (Like every auth system on the web)

Comment: ultimately my suggested solution will be used but with auth implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution is not directly connecting your app with the DB, but to implement that via some layer of API or backend service.

One of the simplest approaches is to use [Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/unity/guide#objects), which is free if your traffic is not very large.

Example code:

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore["score"] = 1337;
gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott";
Task saveTask = gameScore.SaveAsync();
```

---

Another similiar cloud storage or service might be [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), which offers [JSON based API](http://www.roberthorvick.com/2014/03/26/firebase-net-client-library/) for you to read/write your own data. Example usage:

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

var data = new Item(...); // or List<Item>() whatever
var str_data= JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Item>(data);
Firebase fb = new Firebase(new Uri("https://abcdefg.firebaseio.com/"));

//Write
string path = "/path";    // where to keep data in firebase
string id = fb.Post(path, data);

//Read back
string jsonData = fb.Get(path); 
var data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(jsonData);
```